# exclude specific text-based values from comma separated value count and give output excluding those

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I want to count the **;** separated values in a dataframe

solution for that can be something like this

```
count=[] 
for row in gdf.itertuples():
    newstr = row.info.split(";")
    n = len(newstr)
    count.append(n)

gdf["count"] = count
```

However here is an issue i dont want to count those **;** seperated values if they are a specific symbol, in my case its either #, ##, ### or ####
so lets say for image below for id:2 i want the count to be two and for id:6 i want the count to be one and so on

[image]

failed attempts so far

- i tried stripping them before doing the count, i replaced using
  .replace method and # symbols were removed but the separators still
  stayed and made it more messier
- tried len-1 didnt worked
- i tried adding another for loop and if statement which i thought would work
  but no

> ```
> count=[]                            
> for row in gdf.itertuples():
>         newstr = row.info.split(";")
>         for i in newstr:
>             if (i !='#'):
>                 n = len(newstr)
>         count.append(n)
> ```

thanks for the help

Comment: You want to count the chunks separated by `';'`? Count the `;` and add 1 ;) `df['info'].str.count(';').add(1)`. If this is not what you want, please provide sample input data as text (or better, DataFrame constructor) and the matching expected output

Comment: though its more elegant solution then mine but works in the same way and give count for all separated values. i want to exclude those values from the count if it has  any of these four #, ##, ###, ####

Comment: OK, I'll provide a more complete example, but it would be great that you update your question with an explicit, text-based, input/output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the unwanted `##` with a regex, then `count` the `;` and add 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'info': ['1;2;3', '##;2;3', '1;##;3', '1;2;##']})

df['count'] = df['info'].str.replace('#+;|;#+', '', regex=True).str.count(';').add(1)
```

output:

```
     info  count
0   1;2;3      3
1  ##;2;3      2
2  1;##;3      2
3  1;2;##      2
```

regex:

```
#+;   # match one or more literal # followed by ;
|     # OR
;#+   # match one or more literal # preceded by ;
```